# Drag element from iframe to parent frame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, drag-and-drop, postmessage

I have a html page and an iframe in it (They are on the same domain).
I want to be able to drag an element in the iframe to the parent frame.
I tried to find every where but I just can't find helpful ones. 
Is there a way to do it using HTML and JS (no jQuery)?

Comment: @mplungjan They suggest me to use jQuery. I would prefer a way not to use it

Comment: That would be a waste of time. I reopen since I missed the "no jquery" - if you give up, here is one: http://blog.stackhive.com/post/137799349684/building-a-seamless-drag-and-drop-interface